# Logback TimeBasedRollingPolicy not saving the log with the desired name of the log file

Tags: spring-boot, logback

I want to configure TimeBasedRollingPolicy in my spring boot project. I want the log file to be saved in a pattern 'mylog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.

My logback-spring.xml file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="Console"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %15.15t - %-80.80c{1.} %X{username} %X{ipaddress} : %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %15.15t - %-80.80c{1.} %X{username} %X{ipaddress} : %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But it's not working, the log file is created but it is not titled mylog but the default 'localhost_access_log.2022-05-16'. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `timestamp` separately and refer it inside your `fileNamePattern`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <timestamp key="timestamp" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    // place all your appenders
    <appender name="RollingFile"
        .
        .
        .
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${catalina.base}/logs/mylog.${timestamp}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```